# How to determin date below todays date from db in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a pharmacy store project, but I have a problem of determining the total number of drugs that expired. From DB I have:

```
+----+----------+--------+------------+
| id | drug_nam | amount |    exp     |
+----+----------+--------+------------+
| 1  | M and T  |    200 | 04/15/2016 |
| 2  | VIT C    |     20 | 05/25/2016 |
| 3  | Pana     |     10 | 01/03/2016 |
| 4  | Lonat    |   1200 | 08/25/2017 |
| 5  | ProC     |    100 | 05/25/2017 |
+----+----------+--------+------------+
```

what I need here is a line of PHP script that will count the numbers of expired drugs from DB. using `<?php $d = date('m/d/Y'); ?>` to determine it from DB.

I used the code below but it count only 2

```
<?php
$d = date('m/d/Y');
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT count(exp) FROM products where exp < $d ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['count(exp)'];
}
```

Comment: What column type do you use for exp?

Comment: I used `varchar(500)`

Comment: Your date format is not sortable. Use DATE data type or convert your format with `STR_TO_DATE()` function.

Comment: The field exp is a string value becuase you have declared it as a varchar(500) which is lazy on your part. You need to change the exp field to a date datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert your string date representation to date value if you want to filter by date but not by string.
This query should work:

```
SELECT count(exp) FROM products where STR_TO_DATE(exp, '%d/%m/%Y') < $d
```

The main drawback is mysql can't use index in this case. One of the solution is to convert your column from varchar(50) to DATETIME. In this case you can use your original query.

Answer (score 0):

From your table it seems you used some sort of text or varchar for you `exp` column. Cause mysql date format should be like `yyyy-mm-dd`. Please change your `exp` column to `date` and change the below line

```
$d = date('m/d/Y');
```

to

```
$d = date('Y-m-d');
```

That should be good.

Comment: If I change it, Will it count accurate expired drug using my script I showed

Comment: yes it will. The `exp` column should not be `varchar` in the first place.